# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit systemctl doesn't work

Tags: monerod, ubuntu

I installed monero on my server and i can run it without any errors, but the systemctl command won't work for me. This is the status:

```
 ● monero.service - Monero Node Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/monero.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Do 2017-05-11 16:28:59 CEST; 5s ago
  Process: 16477 ExecStart=/opt/monero/monerod (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16477 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Here my /etc/systemd/system/monero.service  file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Monero Node Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/monero/monerod
User=root
WorkingDirectory=~
GuessMainPID=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After run **systemctl start monero.service** the service run for ~10 seconds before exiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/monero/monerod --detach
```